# How can you update less css compiler to the latest version from apt-get?

Tags: css

You can install less css compiler easy:

```
apt-get install lessc
```

But that only installs version 1.1.0. How can you update to the very latest version?

*(The latest version is [1.3.0](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js))*

-- update --

- I want to use the lessc command-line tool, not the client-side implentation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you using it client-side (in the browser)? If so, it's a single JavaScript file, just [download it](http://lesscss.org/).

If you're using it server-side (from a NodeJS application), or want the `lessc` command-line tool, the recommended way to install is using `npm` (the Node Package Manager):

```
npm install less
```

If you don't have `npm`, it's in the Ubuntu 11.10 repositories:

```
sudo apt-get install npm
```

or Using Software Center [image: Install npm via the software center]

Comment: I'm using the command line tool. Too bad it can't simply be installed via apt-get, but npm worked. I did get 2 warnings `npm WARN publish-everything less@1.3.0 Adding entire directory to tarball. Please add a` and `npm WARN publish-everything less@1.3.0 .npmignore or specify a 'files' array in the package.json`

Comment: `npm` is warning you that `less` doesn't specify which files to package up when installing the package. You might want to [file a bug report](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/issues) with the developers, but it should be harmless.

Answer (score 4):

After a lot of head-hitting-desk moments I managed to solve this one.

Originally I had installed lessc using:

```
sudo apt-get install node-less yui-compressor
```

This gave me `lessc 1.2.1` from the command  `lessc -v`

Had to manually download the Quantal version from a repo
http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/pm/node-less

(this gave me ~/Downloads/node-less_1.3.0~20120310-1_all.deb)

Then:

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/node-less_1.3.0~20120310-1_all.deb
```

now I have `lessc 1.3.0`

and:

```
lessc twit-bootstrap_2.0/less/bootstrap.less > /var/tmp/bs.css
```

goes smoothly

Answer (score 2):

As of Ubuntu 12.10, the node-less package installs v1.3.0 of lessc:

```
$ sudo apt-get install node-less
...
$ lessc -v
lessc 1.3.0 (LESS Compiler) [JavaScript]
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because, it is the latest version available in repositories

http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=node-less

Whatever version is present in repositories you have added, apt-get will install only that version.

However if you want to install different version, you should try for other ways

Answer (score 1):

**Just :**

```
npm install less -g
```

or with `sudo`

```
sudo npm install less -g
```

*For checking version :*

```
lessc -v
```

Answer (score 0):

check your version   :

```
node -v
```

you have to update nodejs first

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y python-software-properties python g++ make
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

uninstall less  / and istall again

```
 npm uninstall less
 npm install less
```

check version :

```
lessc -v
```